# Незаконные бандформирования. А есть еще законные?

Tags: употребление-слов

Распространенная терминология "незаконные бандформирования". Откуда она взялась? А что, есть еще и законные бандформирования?))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> А что, есть еще и законные бандформирования?))))

Есть. "Единая Россия", например. :-)

Если серьезно,  то есть термин *Незаконные вооруженные формирования*, по простому это бандиты. Из смешения официальной речи и обыденного языка и появился данный перл. Правда я не уверерен, что его кто-нибудь использовал всерьёз, а не просто шутка Михаила Задорнова.